# Hadoop Streaming :Python Join different files

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have a process which takes input data, processes it and outputs the data.During this it generates two logs IN.log and OUT.log

IN.log contains  when the data came in and the  of the data.
OUT.log contains  when the data was processed and the  of the data.
so...
IN.log contains 
  in-time   id

OUT.log contains
  out-time  id

Now, as part of processing using hadoop streams using python, I would like to join these two files and come with diff of intime and out time and the id of the data .

For eg:

2seconds  id123

3seconds  id112

Any pointers as to how this can be achieved using PYTHON?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you need hadoop, mr and other stuff for?

Comment: These files are going to be pretty big(few GBs),so chose the hadoop way...I was able to achieve this using Hive, but also wanted to check if hadoop streaming provides faster processing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`MRjob`](http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/) helper package for hadoop jobs running. It would be a pretty easy to write a map/reduce for this task, something along the lines of following code

```
from datetime import datetime
from MRJob import MRJob

class JoinJob(MRJob):
    fmt = '%Y-%M-%d'
    def steps(self):
        return [self.mr(mapper=self.mapper, 
                        reducer=self.reducer)]
    def mapper(self, rec_time, rec_id):
        yield rec_id, rec_time

    def reducer(self, rec_id, datetime_strs):
        datetimes = map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, self.fmt), 
                            datetime_strs)
        delta_secs = (max(datetimes) - min(datetimes)).total_seconds()
        yield rec_id, delta_secs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    JoinJob.run()
```